# Updating localstorage arrays in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm having hard time on this localstorage array. Hope you can help me .

here is my code..

```
var bank = document.getElementById('name_bank').value;

function AddBank(bank){ 
  var data = JSON.parse(localStorage.bank); 
    if(!$.inArray( bank, data )){
    data[]=bank;
  }
   localStorage.setItem("bank", JSON.stringify(data)); 
}
```

and i have a error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ]`

Comment: `data[]=bank;` is not valid..

Comment: ` data= [];  data.push(bank);` Use this

Comment: @NishantDixit That'd overwrite the whole variable.

Comment: @NishantDixit ,is not working..

Comment: what do you want to do with `bank` data in if condition?

Comment: @NishantDixit OP wants to update the data. So read it, add element and save it again.

Comment: @MuhammadAshraf Read the link I added in my first comment. That answers your question. Then please accept it as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Please Try This**

```html
<input type="text" id="name_bank" >
<button onclick="AddBank()">
save
</button>
<script>
function AddBank(){
var bank = document.getElementById('name_bank').value;
console.log(bank);
  var data = [];
  aa = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("bank"))
  if(aa != null){
    data= aa;
  }
  if(bank != null){
  data.push(bank)
  }


   localStorage.setItem("bank", JSON.stringify(data));
}
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
var bank = document.getElementById('name_bank').value;

function AddBank(bank){ 
  var data = JSON.parse(localStorage.bank); 
    if(!$.inArray( bank, data )){
    data.push(bank);
  }
   localStorage.setItem("bank", JSON.stringify(data)); 
}
```

Comment: Please try to explain, what you've changed.